# Joomla menu item has "com-akeeba" embedded in the url

Tags: joomla-2.5, menu, menu-item

I am adding a new menu item to my Joomla 2.5 site (can't upgrade to Joomla! 3 due to old version of PHP).

I am adding the menu item "Download" at the top level of the main menu. The url ends up being `mysite.com/com-akeeba/download` instead of `mysite.com/download`.

What is going on? I disabled all of the Akeeba extensions and nothing changed.

Comment: How old PHP then? Old version of PHP can not be an excuse. Upgrade your php and then do the same for Joomla. Regarding the menu item - what is a menu item "Download". Is it a menu item type, or just the title you give it? Do you have any SEF extensions installed? And what is the content you see when you visit the generated ../download URL?

Comment: Actually - it can be. Client requirements stipulate that this exact version of PHP be used. The decision to not upgrade PHP due to other software constraints won out over upgrading PHP for Joomla 3.5.

The menu item "Download" is the name of the menu item, which has the alias "download" and should produce the url siteroot.com/download. No there are no sef extensions. This site is a site that was backed up with akeeba and restored using kickstart. All menu items created after the restore get a 'com-akeeba' between site root and the menu item alias. All the older menu items work correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by opening the `#__menu` table in phpymyadmin, finding the corresponding menu item and editing the `path` column to remove the `com-akeeba` portion.